# Smarty decode {[(NUMBER)]} into NUMBER

Tags: smarty

I have a variable in Smarty with inside : `{[(236)]}`

I'm trying to cast this variable to just retrieve `236`, i tried `json_decode`, `|intval` ... but no effect.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use [PHP str_replace](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php) once for `{[(` and once for `)]}` and replace both of them by empty string `''`.